# Exception: Limit Exceeded: URLFetch URL Length

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, http-get, urlfetch

I am pulling data from an API which unfortunately has very big urls/end points.
Is there any way to shorten urls in order to bypass the Exception: Limit Exceeded: URLFetch URL Length error?

I found this: https://github.com/amitwilson/GoogleAppsScript/blob/master/LinkShortner but I don't know how to use it properly since most of the api calls i make are generated dynamically.

This is an example link (letters after "cursor=" is a cursor key which is different every time):

`https://api.x.immutable.com/v1/orders?include_fees=false&status=filled&buy_token_address=0xacb3c6a43d15b907e8433077b6d38ae40936fe2c&order_by=updated_timestamp&direction=desc&user=0x72a2ffa8be361d4a5d575c55b7382d8c6317f77d&page_size=200&cursor=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_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`

Comment: I got data using - omitting the *user* parameter: i.e. https://api.x.immutable.com/v1/orders?include_fees=false&status=filled&buy_token_address=0xacb3c6a43d15b907e8433077b6d38ae40936fe2c&order_by=updated_timestamp&direction=desc - try to remove `&user=...` from the url.

Comment: Yeah but those data are wrong ones, i need the full data like the link on my first post. Thanks

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I think that your showing script can be used. So, I cannot understand `but I don't know how to use it properly since most of the api calls i make are generated dynamically.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: You may try sending it as a ``payload`` body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your situation, for example, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, please set `apiKey` and `yourDynamicLinkDomain`. Your `yourDynamicLinkDomain` might be like `https://###.page.link`.

```js
const apiKey = "###"; // Please set your API key.
const yourDynamicLinkDomain = "###"; // Please set your dynamic link domain.

function getShortUrl_(longUrl) {

  const url = "https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=" + apiKey;
  const options = {
    payload: JSON.stringify({
      dynamicLinkInfo: {
        dynamicLinkDomain: yourDynamicLinkDomain,
        link: longUrl,
      },
    }),
    contentType: "application/json",
  };
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  const { shortLink } = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
  return shortLink;
}

// Please run this function.
function main() {

  // do something for retrieving the long URL in your actual script.
  const longUrl = "###"; // It supposes that your long URL is put to longUrl.

  const shortUrl = getShortUrl_(longUrl); // Here, the long URL is shortned. You can use this.

  // If "options" is required to be used, please use this.
  const options = {

  };
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(shortUrl, options);

}
```

- In this sample script, it supposes that by your current script, `longUrl` is obtained. And, this sample script converts from the long URL to the short URL with the function `getShortUrl_`. And, you can use this short URL using UrlFetchApp.

#### Note:

- This sample script supposes that you have already been able to use Firebase Dynamic Links API. Please be careful about this.

  - If you have never been able to be used Firebase Dynamic Links API, please check [the official document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest). And, the following flow might be useful.
    please check the following flow.

    1. Please create a new Firebase project and link it to your Google Cloud Platform Project. [Ref](https://console.firebase.google.com/)

       - At this time, please set `dynamicLinkDomain` at "Dynamic Links".
    2. Please enable Firebase Dynamic Links API at the API console.
    3. Please create your API key from your Google Cloud Platform Project.

       - Please use this API in the above script.
- When I tested this script, I could confirm that the long URL is converted to the short URL and the short URL can be used with UrlFetchApp.
- If I misunderstood about `but I don't know how to use it properly since most of the api calls i make are generated dynamically.`, please tell me.

#### References:

- [Create Dynamic Links with the REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest)
- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

### Added:

From your following reply,

> Hey I made a sample sheet so you can see how I get the longurl it is highlighted with yellow color in 202 row. docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/… The API works like this: it can pull 200 rows, then on the last row of each call it shows this cursor ID which must be called again in next row in order to show the next 200 rows.

> Check the sample sheet on my previous reply. Longurl is highlighted with YELLOW color.

When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, it seems that you are using the long URL as `=importjson(CONCATENATE("https://api.x.immutable.com/v1/orders?include_fees=false&status=filled&buy_token_address=0xacb3c6a43d15b907e8433077b6d38ae40936fe2c&order_by=updated_timestamp&direction=desc&user=0x8604808B824C4444Fe4dF3f94850ACd584C5aD7d&page_size=200&cursor=",W202),"","noTruncate,noHeaders")`. But unfortunately, from your question and your reply, I couldn't notice that you are using it like that.

In this case, it is required to use my sample script by modifying as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of your Spreadsheet and save the script.

```js
function getShortUrl(longUrl) {
  const apiKey = "###"; // Please set your API key.
  const yourDynamicLinkDomain = "###"; // Please set your dynamic link domain.

  const url = "https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=" + apiKey;
  const options = {
    payload: JSON.stringify({
      dynamicLinkInfo: {
        dynamicLinkDomain: yourDynamicLinkDomain,
        link: longUrl,
      },
    }),
    contentType: "application/json",
  };
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  const { shortLink } = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
  return shortLink;
}
```

- When this script is used for your sample Spreadsheet, please put the following formula to the cell "A203".

  ```
    =importjson(getShortUrl(CONCATENATE("https://api.x.immutable.com/v1/orders?include_fees=false&status=filled&buy_token_address=0xacb3c6a43d15b907e8433077b6d38ae40936fe2c&order_by=updated_timestamp&direction=desc&user=0x8604808B824C4444Fe4dF3f94850ACd584C5aD7d&page_size=200&cursor=",W202)),"","noTruncate,noHeaders")
  ```

  - By this formula, the long URL retrieved with `CONCATENATE("https://api.x.immutable.com/v1/orders?include_fees=false&status=filled&buy_token_address=0xacb3c6a43d15b907e8433077b6d38ae40936fe2c&order_by=updated_timestamp&direction=desc&user=0x8604808B824C4444Fe4dF3f94850ACd584C5aD7d&page_size=200&cursor=",W202)` is shorten by `shortenUrl()`. And, use the shorten URL with `importjson`.

#### Note:

- This sample script supposes that you have already been able to use Firebase Dynamic Links API. Please be careful about this.
- When I tested the above script and formula to your sample Spreadsheet, I confirmed that the values are retrieved.

Comment: @doubleunary Thank you for editing it. I couldn't notice the spelling mistake.

Comment: I've made it a habit to `'use strict';`.

Comment: Does this script work with dynamic longurl? I get the longurl from API calls which are different every time.

Comment: @MrFrank Thank you for replying. About `Does this script work with dynamic longurl? I get the longurl from API calls which are different every time.`, although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand `dynamic longurl` you are thinking, in this sample script, if the `dynamic longurl` is retrieved from your API and put to `longUrl`, the `dynamic longurl` can be shortened.

Comment: Yes dynamic longurl is retrieved from my API. But how i can add it automatically to the script? So I don't copy paste it manually?

Comment: @MrFrank Thank you for replying. About `Yes dynamic longurl is retrieved from my API. But how i can add it automatically to the script? So I don't copy paste it manually?`, when you retrieve `dynamic longurl` in a script, you can put it to `longUrl`. From your question and your reply, I understood that in your situation, you are retrieving `dynamic longurl` using a script. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @MrFrank If you are retrieving `dynamic longurl` using a script, when you can provide it, the script might be able to be merged with my proposed script.

Comment: Hey I made a sample sheet so you can see how I get the longurl it is highlighted with yellow color in 202 row.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fUJKKLE3wdw0V-fe9bnFjSzzgVN686ch1eav7lvlcHU/edit#gid=0
The API works like this: it can pull 200 rows, then on the last row of each call it shows this cursor ID which must be called again in next row in order to show the next 200 rows.

Comment: @MrFrank Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your reply. Can I ask you about the detail of your reply?

Comment: Check the sample sheet on my previous reply. Longurl is highlighted with YELLOW color.

Comment: @MrFrank Thank you for replyin. When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, it seems that you are using the long URL as `=importjson("longURL",W202),"","noTruncate,noHeaders")`. But, unfortunately, from your question and your reply, I couldn't notice that you are using it like that. I deeply apologize for this. From your sample Spreadsheet, I added the method for using it. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Hey thank you for the update! I added your script to the sample sheet above but I get errors. Can you check it there please?

Comment: @MrFrank Thank you for replying. About `Hey thank you for the update! I added your script to the sample sheet above but I get errors. Can you check it there please?`, I cannot understand the detail of it. Because when I tested my proposed script, no error occurs. But I would like to support you. So, in order to correctly understand your new issue, can you provide more information?

Comment: Check the sample sheet, scripts and data are there. You can see errors too when running it. Thanks

Comment: @MrFrank Thank you for replying. I have to apologize. Now, I noticed that I had miscopied the function name. My function name is `getShortUrl`. So, please modify `=importjson(shortenUrl(CONCATENATE("https:/:...` to `=importjson(getShortUrl(CONCATENATE("https:/:...` and test it again.

Comment: Hey now i get this error: "Error
Exception: Bad request: http://#ERROR! (line 223)."

Comment: @MrFrank Thank you for replying. About `Hey now i get this error: "Error Exception: Bad request: http://#ERROR! (line 223)."`, when by copying your values to my Spreadsheet and I tested my script, no error occurs. I apologize for this. By the way, what is `line 223`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245956/discussion-between-mrfrank-and-tanaike).